# How to automatically renew DHCP IP?

Tags: dhcp

I have a headless server on my network (actually it's just running Ubuntu Desktop 10.04) that for some reason isn't automatically renewing its DHCP lease when it gets reconnected to the network.  How do I fix this?

Some more info: the router our systems are connected to has been going down and coming back up occasionally, in the span of a second.  The other Ubuntu 10.04 boxes seem to handle this fine - within a second, they're connected again.  It's just this one box that doesn't seem to be behaving.  It's annoying because every time this happens I have to go to the server and reconnect a monitor (or at the very least a keyboard) just to run `sudo dhclient`.

```
$ pgrep NetworkManager 
1014

$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS
Release:        10.04
Codename:       lucid
```

Comment: How are you using NetworkManager on a headless server?

Comment: @Thomas That's why I pointed out that it's running Ubuntu Desktop 10.04.  I just call it a headless server to describe how I use it - as a headless server.

Comment: Dont know exactly why this is happening. It could also be a problem with the router. Perhaps try upgrading the router firmware first specially if you have issues with it restarting. Also why not configure your router to allocate an ip address to your machine, then you can set that ip address manually to static and dont have to worry about DHCP. That way you can also SSH to the same IP and not worry about DHCP changing the address of your server on you.

Comment: @Aras The router situation is unfortunate but one that we (for the time being) have no control over. I am not the administrator of this network.

Comment: Close voters: Ubuntu 10.04 Server edition **is not EOL**. Per the Ubuntu release page support for 10.04 Lucid Lynx Server Edition ends April 2015. Without further information **this is not off-topic**.

Comment: @Yang could you please run `apt-cache policy ubuntu-desktop | grep Installed` and `apt-cache policy ubuntu-server* | grep Installed`?